# How to conditionally compile VC6 resources

Tags: mfc, resources, visual-c++-6, conditional-compilation

depending on a compile switch  (values are `COMPILE_A` or `COMPILE_B`), which is set in the form of an envorinment variable, I want to compile my application with different settings, like application name and splash screen.

I got this far:

1. In "Project / Settings / C/C++ / Preprocessor Definitions" I added `$(COMPILESWITCH)` (results in command line option `/D "$(COMPILESWITCH)"`).
2. In stdafx.h I can use the following code, which means I correctly defined the preprocessor definition via the command line parameter:

```
    #if defined COMPILE_A
    #   define IDB_SPLASH IDB_SPLASH_A
    # elif defined COMPILE_B
    #   define IDB_SPLASH IDB_SPLASH_B
    # else
    #   error Unknown or undefined target compile switch; cannot compile!
    # endif
```

But I've noticed the "Condition" property under "ResourceView / [right-click] / Properties"...
The help text says this:

> Condition
>
> Determines the inclusion of
>   the resource. For example, if the
>   condition is _DEBUG, this resource
>   would be included only in debug
>   builds.

This looks like the elegant way of doing it, right?

Specifiying `_DEBUG` as condition works. So as `_DEBUG` is specified via `/D _DEBUG` my `$(COMPILESWITCH)` should also work, right?
For some reason it doesn't; why?

Or is there even another, better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I just solved my problem...

The resource compiler uses its own preprocessor.
Therefore the same preprocessor definition has to be added under "Project / Settings / Resources / Preprocessor Definitions".

#### Edit: String Resources

The above doesn't work for string resources as they don't have a "condition" property...

I chose to use the `res\<projectname>.rc2` custom resource file which won't be touched by the resource editor.
The content looks like this

```
#if defined(COMPILE_A)
    STRINGTABLE DISCARDABLE 
    BEGIN
        IDR_MAINFRAME           "AppTitle A"
    END
#else
#   if defined(COMPILE_B)
    STRINGTABLE DISCARDABLE 
    BEGIN
        IDR_MAINFRAME           "AppTitle B"
    END
#   else
#       error Compile switch not defined or unknown; cannot compile!
#   endif
#endif
```